# How to secure an MVC4 Route and update the ActionLink that contains an OAuth parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, oauth

Imagine that you have a page where the route /Checkout/Complete/1 completes an order of OAuth google UserID 1. This is implemented in an ActionLink as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Submit>>", "Complete", "Checkout",
    new { id = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId }, null)
```

Now the big flaw in this approach is that users of the site that filled up their shopping cart can just enter a link like /Checkout/Complete/2 and place the order on another UserId so that they do not have to pay.

What I tried to do is make an entry in routeconfig that looks as follows:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    int currentUserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Checkout",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new {controller = "Checkout", action = "Complete", id = 
                                                     UrlParameter.Optional},
        constraints: new { id = currentUserId } 
        );
}
```

Unfortunately this approach does not work.

How do I make a constraint that checks if the Websecurity.CurrentUserId matches the actual currentUserId and otherwise refers to an error page? If there are better ways to accomplish this goal I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay just by typing out the question I got a better idea of what I was trying to accomplish. I solved the problem by adding the if-statement (id == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId) to the CheckoutController file as follows:

```
// GET: /Checkout/Complete
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Complete(int id)
{
     if (id == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
     {
     //do stuff
     }
     else {
     //tell user to not do that
     }
}
```

This works!

Unfortunately when you visit for example /Checkout/Complete/joe we still get the message that

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable 
type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Complete(Int32)'
```

I think this does need to be fixed with a constraint in the routeconfig.cs. Anyone any idea how?

Comment: "Joe" is not an integer, that route needs a numeric user id. But yes this is fundamentally not a routing issue, it's a security issue, so this approach is the best.

Comment: @Mansfield, how would you go about for arranging pages that do not exist like the /Checkout/Complete/Joe one. They display an ugly error message now. Is there a possibility to reroute all those to a common 404 page or something went wrong page?

Comment: Yes, you need to use custom error handling. Post a new question about that.